# Calendar API Login Required

Tags: php, laravel, api, calendar

I tried adding the google calendar API and as response i got this error

```
 Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 118:
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "Login Required",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
}
],
"code": 401,
"message": "Login Required"
}
}
```

**App/Providers/GoogleClientServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class GoogleClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    function register(){
        /* Get config variables */
        $service_account_name = getenv('GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME');
        $key_file_location = base_path() . getenv('GOOGLE_KEY_FILE_LOCATION');

        $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
        /* Add the scopes you need */
        $scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];

        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $this->cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

        $cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $service_account_name,
            $scopes,
            $key
        );


        $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

        // repeat this block for as many Google_Services_* as you like
        // don't forget to add scopes for other services.
        $this->app->singleton(\Google_Service_Calendar::class, function ($app) use ($client) {
            return new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);
        });
    }

}
```

**App/http/Controllers/AgendaController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Google_Service_Calendar;
use App\kosten;
use App\User;

class AgendaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Google_Service_Calendar $client){
      $calendarList = $client->calendarList->listCalendarList();
      dd($calendarList->getItems());
    }  

    // public function index()
    // {


    //   return view('agenda');
    // }
}
```

GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME=GOOGLESERVICEACCOUNT
GOOGLE_KEY_FILE_LOCATION=/resources/assets/key.p12

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code :

```
 putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' .get_include_path().'/yourPath/client_secret.json');
    define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
            Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
    ));

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    $client->setApplicationName("MasterSinge");

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
```

Comment: Have you got the latest Google Api Calendar ?

Comment: How do i check if i got the latest version? My collegue downloaded it

Comment: @MarioEekma Google Calendar API v2 is deprecated, I suggest to download this: [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)  Check if you have the right path for your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. You can create an another service account and download the JSON.